# Oracle Sample HR schema :: specify default tablespeace for HR as parameter 2

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I have downloaded [Oracle Database Sample Schemas](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas) from GitHub and I'm following the official guide about how to [import the HR schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-CB945E4C-D08A-4B26-A12D-3D6D688467EA) manually.

Oracle SQL Developer prompt me with this banner: `Enter value for 2:`

[image]

Which is caused by the lines:

```
PROMPT specify default tablespeace for HR as parameter 2:
DEFINE tbs      = &2
```

Now.

Being an official guide for newbies I expect at least an explication about the value I need to enter.

Especially because Oracle is providing the data so they must know if the default value should be 2, 200, 2000, etc..

- What should I enter there?
- A number or a string?
- Are these Kb or Mb?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the name of a `TABLESPACE`; this is specified in the [instructions in the `README.md` file](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas#25--run-the-installation-script) in the Github repository:

> Use your current SYSTEM and SYS passwords, and also your actual default and temporary tablespace names. The passwords for the new HR, OE, PM, IX, SH and BI users will be set to the values you specify.

If you have not got an existing `TABLESPACE` that you want to use then you need to create one using the [`CREATE TABLESPACE` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm).

I.e. [one example is](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm#i2153401):

```sql
CREATE TABLESPACE tbs_01 DATAFILE 'tbs_f2.dat' SIZE 40M ONLINE;
```

Then, if you didn't have an existing tablespace you wanted to use and had used the above command, the value you would need to provide is: `tbs_01`